# React Leaflet map - removeLayer error when rerendered

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to make a leaflet map in Next.js (React). In my application I have context, where I store all waypoints, so that I can also show location name in different component.

Here is a piece of code where the error happens.

```
const createRoutingMachineLayer = useCallback(() => {
    const instance = L.Routing.control({
      waypoints: waypoints,
      lineOptions: {
        styles: [{ color: "blue", weight: 2 }],
        extendToWaypoints: true,
        missingRouteTolerance: 20,
      },
      plan: L.Routing.plan(waypoints, {
        createMarker: function (i, wp) {
          return L.marker(wp.latLng)
            .addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
              //here is the PROBLEM
              updatePointById(routePoints[i].id, e.target._latlng);
            });
        },
      }),
      show: false,
      addWaypoints: false,
      routeWhileDragging: true,
      fitSelectedRoutes: true,
      showAlternatives: false,
      router: L.Routing.mapbox(accessToken, {
        profile: "mapbox/cycling",
      }),
    })

    return instance;

  }, [waypoints]);
```

When I drag a Marker, I want to also update coordinates of the waypoint which returns new waypoints array from context.

This rerenderes the createRoutingMachineLayer and this I think creates error message:  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeLayer')

EDIT: I have added a functionality that removes Marker on click, which changes the waypoints, but it doesnt throw the error.

- it seems, that the problem is in the dragend event

How do I remove this error message? How to prevent it?